# Using webpack bundle analyzer with angular workspace file

Tags: json, angular, webpack, ng-packagr, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I am trying to optimize the [ng2-smart-table package](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table), which we are using as a dependency, as I have noticed it has a big unnecessary dependency on [lodash](https://lodash.com/), even though it only uses a tiny portion of lodash.

However, I'm running into some issues when trying to get [webpack bundle analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to work with their `angular.json` [workspace file](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config).

If I just try to run ng build I get this:

```
❯ ng build --statsJson
Unknown option: '--statsJson'
❯ ng build --stats-json
Unknown option: '--stats-json'
```

Now, the project uses an `angular.json` workspace file with the following contents:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ng2-smart-table": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/ng2-smart-table",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/ng2-smart-table/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/ng2-smart-table/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/ng2-smart-table/ng-package.json"
          }
        },
        ...
```

If I try to add `"statsJson": true` to the options I get this error:

```
❯ ng build ng2-smart-table
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(statsJson).
```

I suspect it has something to do with the project using `@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build` rather than the standard `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser`. However, since the packagr apparently doesn't support analysis I just don't know how I can get my analysis file generated.

Comment: you may want to use `lodash-es` its probably will better reduce amount of used lodash code if you use only few functions

Answer (score 0):

As to the error itself: According to [Angular CLI docs](https://angular.io/cli/build), the `--stats-json` option cannot be used with a library project type.

> The command can be used to build a project of type "application" or "library". When used to build a library, a different builder is invoked, and only the `ts-config`, `configuration`, and `watch` options are applied. All other options apply only to building applications.

Answer (score -2):

You need to specify project if you are using a workspace such as

```
ng build myproject --statsJson
```

Comment: How to generate stas.json for Angular library, since the command is just for Angular projects?

Answer (score -2):

Go to angular.json file and check "projects" section.

```
"projects": {
    "template": { <--- here
        "projectType": "application",
        "schematics": {},
```

Then run `ng build template --statsJson`

In your case it's `ng build ng2-smart-table --statsJson`